# AIX Ksh grep script issue

Tags: linux, unix, ksh, aix

I have this script that I had help with basically grep from specific file

It worked on RHEL 8 with Ksh but at my work with AIX 7.1 Doesn't work.

Gives me this error: 0404-057 Syntax error at line 6 : '(' is not expected

My script:

```
#!/use/bin/ksh
If [[ $# -eq 0]];
Then
Echo"add value please"
Else
For ((I = $#; I > 0; i--)); do
Grep -w -- "$1" responselist.lst || echo "'$1' not found"
Shift
Done
Fi
```

Comment: You need to check which `ksh` you are using, `ksh93/pdksh/mksh` ?

Comment: @philippe how to do that

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199900/how-can-i-safely-get-the-version-of-ksh

Comment: Try `/usr/bin/ksh93` instead

Comment: The loop should be: `for i in "$@"; do grep -w "$i"...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @shawn for the answer.

The issue was the version

This worked

`/usr/bin/ksh93`

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to try:

```
#!/use/bin/ksh
if [[ "$#" -eq 0 ]]; then
  echo "add value please"
else
  for ((i = $#; i > 0; i--)); do
    grep -w "$1" responselist.lst || echo "$1 not found"
    Shift
  done
fi
```